# How can i download the images from the site by date and hours until the date is changed?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

It's archive.
The starting date and time is: 24/6/2016 and 13:10 noon.
I want to download in loop until the date 24/6/2016 change to 25/6/2016

The images are in a 10 minute frequency.

The format isi n the link below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace Search_Text_In_Files
{
    class DownloadRadarImages
    {
        private void DownloadImages()
        {
            string imageslinks = "http://www.meteoswiss.admin.ch/product/output/radar-processing/VRAG05.CCSK_20160624_1310.png";

            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(imageslinks), @"c:\temp\image35.png");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe something like that in the idea the code is not good but something like this maybe

```
private void DownloadImages()
        {
            int countTime = 0;

            while (true)
            {
                string imageslinks = "http://www.meteoswiss.admin.ch/product/output/radar-processing/VRAG05.CCSK_20160624_" + countTime + ".png";
                using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                {
                    client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(imageslinks), @"c:\temp\" + countTime + ".png");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you have the list of images with you? Else I don't think you can really guess the name of the images with date and time combination. There can far too many combinations.

Comment: Before you even think of how to stop you need to rethink how to start, you can't just permanently download from a site non stop like that, it will at best kill your connection, at worse kill theirs and either way likely get you IP banned from it. Use a timer and download when you need to (for exemple every 2 minuets, but not every 10 milliseconds like this like will)

Comment: @AnkitVijay The images are in a 10 minute frequency (the OP should have added this to the question)

Comment: @AnkitVijay i did a small test with the link above in my and changed it from 13:10 to 13:00 then to 12:50 so the jumpes of the times are in 10 minutes. So about the date i'm not sure but the time i think by jumps of 10 minutes.

Comment: @AnkitVijay i will update it in my question.

Comment: @RonanThibaudau you right while is a bad idea. I will use a timer.

Comment: You have to look at the rules on that site if there are any limits or if you have to pay for an unlimited access. After that research you can implement a solution which respect the rules. Anything else is just a **maybe** solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Microsoft's Reactive Framework for this. Just NuGet "Rx-Main" before you try this code:

```
string imageslinks = "http://www.meteoswiss.admin.ch/product/output/radar-processing/VRAG05.CCSK_20160624_1310.png";
Func<long, string> createFileName = n => String.Format(@"C:\temp\image-{0}-{1}.png", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"), n);

var query =
    Observable
        .Timer(TimeSpan.FromDays(0.0), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10.0))
        .TakeUntil(DateTimeOffset.Now.Date.AddDays(1.0))
        .SelectMany(n =>
            Observable
                .Using(
                    () => new WebClient(),
                    wc => Observable.FromAsync(() => wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(imageslinks), createFileName(n)))));

var subscription =
    query
        .Subscribe(u => Console.Write("."));
```

I've tested this and it works just fine.

If you need to stop the subscription early just call `subscription.Dispose()`.

Comment: This is working great for the first image and if i want to use it with the timer to get more images ?

Comment: @מנימנחם - This does have a timer already - the `Observable.Timer` part is the timer. It's set for a 10 minute interval - did you wait long enough for the second image to download? I tested it with `FromSeconds` to see that it worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/henrikn/2012/02/17/httpclient-downloading-to-a-local-file/) which explain how to download a file to local.

You would also need to get the list of image url you need to download. For that you can use a helper method like below: (Warning: Not tested)

```
public List<string> GetImages(string baseAddress, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) {

        var imageList = new List<string>();
        while (startDate < endDate) {
            var dateString = startDate.ToString("yyyymmdd");
            var timeString = startDate.ToString("HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);

            imageList.Add($"{baseAddress}_{dateString}_{timeString}.png"); //C# 6.0 feature.
            startDate = startDate.AddMinutes(10);

        }

        return imageList;

}
```